# git remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch

Tags: git, netbeans, git-push, git-remote

I am using git inside netbeans IDE. I wanted to change the commit message for the most recent commit I had made. I did that, checked the `amend last commit` checkbox and committed it to my local repository. When I push this commit to my github repo, I get the error: `git remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch. open output to see more information.` How do I fix this ? I am new to source control. I only want to do very basic version control with my current project. Please tell me how to fix this.

**Screen:**

[image]

**Output message:**

```
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://github.com/double-whammy/netbeans_affablebean.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : id1
New Id        : id2
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD
Local Repository Updates
Branch Update : origin/master
Old Id        : id1
New Id        : id2
Result        : NOT_ATTEMPTED
==[IDE]== Pushing - AffableBean finished.
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I read the error message once again and thought that I should merge the local branch into remote branch. I looked around in the IDE to find these options. I got lucky when I tried:
`Project > right click > Git > repository browser`.

**The following window opens up:**

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Remote branch > right click > merge revision. Then you will see the hash of remote next to local.
2. Project > Right click > Git > Remote > Push. This will push your local branch code to remote repo.

Comment: In my case, I had to do another commit after step 1.

Comment: In my case, I needed to go to Remotes (not Remote, Remote**s**) > right click > Fetch and then I could proceed to Step 1

Answer (score 11):

Realize a pull. Then a window with the option 'merge' will appear. Do a merge and try to push it again.

Sorry for my english level

Comment: This also worked for me. My problem was I created a README.md file before I did a push from Netbeans. I deleted the README, but it just saw there were commits remotely that it didn't have so didn't allow me to push until I pulled first. But yeah maybe I should do Daniel's suggestion in another answer to fetch then merge instead. I like to see whats happening.

Answer (score 9):

> Don’t use git pull, use git fetch, then git merge, then git commit and then git push.

FYI: http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/

Answer (score 1):

If you can not see the file under remote in the git repository browser then first you need to pull in order to solve the above problem.
**Steps:**
1.Right click project > Git > Remote > Pull > then select merge option.
2.Right click project > Git > Remote > Push.
The problem should be solved by now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project > Git > Remote > fetch
Right click your project > Git > Branch/ tag > Merge Revision
Click merge
Now u should be able to do the push...

Answer (score 0):

I would delete the repository. Recreate the repository. Please don't commit anything. Then push it after adding and committing inside NetBeans. Remember, you can create README.md, anything later.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's already solved.
just want to post it down here.
I had the same error as yours but it happened because i modified my repository in github and didn't pull it to my local repository.

you need to `remote > pull` and then choose `rebase`.

that's what i did