# Netbeans 8.0.1 - Remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch

Tags: java, git, netbeans, bitbucket

I followed the below instructions to push a Java project in Netbeans 8.0.1 into a Bitbucket repository, but following error popped up:

[image]

Project > Team > Git > Initialize

Project > Right Click > Team > Commit

Project > Team > Remote > Push > ...

I tried to solve this issue following the procedure in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027653/git-remote-repository-contains-commits-unmerged-into-the-local-branch), but no success.

Comment: you probably need to pull from remote and merge before pushing.

Comment: yes thanks, I did it and worked, please submit your correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is saying that your local repository is not up to date with the remote repository. You need to pull from the remote repo and merge or discard changes if necessary. Once that is done you should be able to push your commits.

Comment: I merged but no luck still complains the same message. When I merge how should I select the branch and the commit...??

Comment: @MikeIT Hard to say without more information - you should ask a separate question with the details of your problem.