# How to remote push in another Git repository from different Git repository?

Tags: git, github

I've checked out read-only Git repository, which is published by someone else for learning purpose. Now, I'm making some changes in local for learning and I've created local branches for different changes.

I cannot push those branches to remote as it's not my repository (no write permission).
If I try then get this error:

> git-receive-pack not permitted

What I want is, I can push changes so I can save and access those changes remotely from anywhere.
I've created my own Git repository but I've not much experience with Git, so not sure how can I save my changes from current repository to my repository.

Also, is it possible that I can continue working in the same remote repository (because sometimes I've to pull changes to remote repository from where I'm learning) and I can push remotely to my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to fork the repository.

> A fork is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project.

[image: fork]

You can continue to pull and merge changes from the original repo, and send pull requests if you've made improvements.

[image: url]

After pressing the `fork` button, update your remote using the clone URL:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/coolzero/infinity.git
```

Comment: Thanks @Huey, your answer was useful. Though I found some issues after above steps in Netbeans but I got it resolved from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25029847/555953